# Data preparation for classification models

Tags: logistic, classification, categorical-data, random-forest, factor-analysis

I am trying to predict user response (binary output 1 or 0) based on several interaction factors.
After merging all information by user, my database looks like the table below :

| ID | Interaction_Type | Time_Since_Response | Frequency | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Email | 0-2 months | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | Email | 3-4 months | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | Email | 5-6 months | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Phone | 5-6 months | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Phone | 0-2 months | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Phone | 3-4 months | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Phone | 5-6 months | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Email | 3-4 months | 6 | 0 |

I was thinking of a logistic model or random forest classifier to predict the variable "Response".

My question is about my dataframe.
Do I have to pivot the table to get one row by individual like below before applying the model? I have 6 interactions type, and 3 categories (time interval) in time_since_Response

| ID | Email[0-2m] | Email[3-4m] | Email[5-6m] | Phone[0-2m] | Phone[3-4m] | Phone[5-6m] | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

What methods do you usually apply with this type of data?